# Speed up the process of creating the performance report

Tags: android, macros, automation, excel-2010, adb

Using ADB top command i fetch cpu logs in command prompt mode. txt file automatically saved in SD card path.i get that logs and split the values 
Using Excel i split those values using text to columns options. Is there any automation script (or) macro to speed up the process?

Comment: _"Using Excel i split those values using text to columns options"_ It isn't clear. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Please show code of what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use the script `adb shell top -n 1 > top-results.txt` to dump the top output directly to a file on your computer without having to get the file from the SD card on the phone.

Comment: i already used top command but i need automation script like i have txt file in that file the values like PID-423  PR-0   CPU-0% S-S    #THR-1     VSS- 0K      RSS-0K  PCY-fg UID-root     NAME-cfinteractive0 i want to fetch CPU value only and place in excel sheet like S.no 1 CPU 2% s.no.2 CPU 4%